# Can w show the full IP address?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

When I use the `w` command on Ubuntu Server 14.04 I get output looking like this:

```
 18:44:24 up 4 days,  3:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
kd       pts/0    2001:db8:1334:2c 12:54    0.00s  0.06s  0.00s w
```

As you can see the IP address has been truncated. Is there any way I can get `w` to show the full IP address without truncation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the `man` page for `w.procps`:

```
trusty (1) w.procps.1.gz
Provided by: procps_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_i386 bug

NAME
       w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.

...  

ENVIRONMENT
   PROCPS_USERLEN
          Override  the default width of the username column.  Defaults to
          8.

   PROCPS_FROMLEN
          Override the default width of the from column.  Defaults to 16.
```

For example,

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ w
 13:30:24 up 6 days, 20:32,  3 users,  load average: 4.08, 3.43, 3.12
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
w3       tty1                      19Nov16 25:51m  0.40s  0.38s -bash
w3       tty7     :0               19Nov16  6days 11:37m  2.41s /sbin/upstart --user
w3       pts/16   192.168.100.254  13:20    9:34   0.25s  0.25s -bash
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ env PROCPS_FROMLEN=48 w
 13:30:36 up 6 days, 20:32,  3 users,  load average: 3.68, 3.36, 3.10
USER     TTY      FROM                                             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
w3       tty1                                                      19Nov16 25:51m  0.40s  0.38s -bash
w3       tty7     :0                                               19Nov16  6days 11:37m  2.41s /sbin/upstart --user
w3       pts/16   192.168.100.254                                  13:20    9:46   0.25s  0.25s -bash
```

Comment: That's cool!  I guess I didn't read down far enough.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your solution is to use `last -w` which will not truncate the hostname.

To filter your results to see who is logged in currently, a simply `grep` will do.

```
last -w | grep "logged in"
```